# How would I create a file directory relative to a users documents in C#?

Tags: c#, file, save

I am trying to create a save file directory in XNA, I have an XML serializer setup that stores scores from the game, but when the game first runs I want it to create the file in the users documents in a folder called SaveData. I can create the XML file itsef, but I am not sure how to create it in the users documents, since the username is different every time?

So my question is how would I save in documents relative to any username?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you get started:

> [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx)([Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx));